# Bootstrap 4: Text on image displaced on difference screen size

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want the text to look like this on my image:
[image]
which is slightly away from the "Center" point of the image(as i want to avoid the phone in the image), so text-center wouldnt work. I currently set the division of the row to "relative" and the text to "Absolute" in order to even get the text on top of the image. But when i resize the image, it will be displaced.

Code:

```
<section>
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"style="margin: 0;padding: 0;position: relative;">
    <img class="img-fluid" style="width:100%;" src="img/phone-transparent.png" alt=""></img>
    <h2 style="color:red;position: absolute; top: 120px; width: 100%;">This is also</br>available on your mobile.</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

On original screensize:
[image]

On a different screensize:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or site ?

Comment: I don't have fiddle, not quite sure what site means... I'm doing all my testing using localhost, IDE: Atom

Comment: Okay To accomplish this u can write media query for mobile devices

Comment: Okay, I'll try to solve and edit / answer if solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using only Bootstrap 4 classes. **Read the documentation** on [using the grid](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), and the [utility classes for positioning and flexbox](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/). You don't need all the inline CSS styles.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="row no-gutter align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
            <img class="img-fluid position-relative mx-auto" src="//placehold.it/1900x400" alt="">
            <h3 class="w-100 position-absolute text-danger my-auto">This is also<br>available on your mobile.</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://www.codeply.com/go/YkRhrBYQ6o)

> Remember that `.col-*` *must* be placed in the `.row`, and the `.row`
>   should be inside a container.

You can use the [spacing utils](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) and [CSS `object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) on the image to get the position and size: [**Demo 2**](https://www.codeply.com/go/Te8MuDfCkc) (*you* will need to tweak this as desired).